# Laptop does not POST

Tags: laptop, motherboard, bios

I have a Socket 7 based laptop which i bought from a garage sale recently. When i press the power button, it makes three short beeps and it turns off instantly. If i press the power button again it does the same thing.

I have looked online for the beep codes and it is related to the base 64K memory failure. But i have tried other memory modules and i even tried it without a CPU installed and it still makes the symptom.

```
 What's known:
```

- the CMOS battery is a rechargeable lithium cell that does not maintain a charge (it's dead).
- the CPU is a Pentium 90 MHz that is working perfectly

Here are some photos of the motherboard:

[image]
[image]

What could be wrong ?

Comment: The post says it, the base memory, which is NOT the RAM chips, but a chip on the motherboard. So basically the motherboard is dying or alraedy died.

Comment: From what I have read about this AMI board, it looks like replacing the RAM/ trying one at a time, etc has resolved the issue for them. Other people have reported that it was, in fact, their memory controller and had to replace the motherboard.

Comment: I've updated the post. Near the CPU is most likely cache and near the mouse buttons there are video memory chips (i guess).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit awkward (answering my own question) but i want to share the solution.

If you have an old made in germany 90s laptop with Amibios that makes three beeps and powers off, it MIGHT NOT BE A 64K MEMORY FAILURE as they say on the internet.

In my situation, the problem was the **battery**. So i went ahead and opened the battery to find out that the cells were completely flat (of course). Next, i removed the cells and soldered two thick wires on the battery terminal so i can power the laptop from the outside.
[image]

I gave it 12V and tried to power it on. This is the result (i think the vertical lines are caused by the faulty LCD) :
[image]

And no, this laptop does not have onboard system memory.